# Plot N equidistant points on a circle, only giving one point

Tags: java, javafx, plot, geometry, points

So I need to plot n equally spaced points along the circumference of a circle. I have the code here but it only plots 1 point. It's probably just one little thing but I can't figure it out. Here's what I have:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;

public class jvafx extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {     
        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 300, Color.LIGHTGREY);

        Circle c = new Circle();
        c.setCenterX(150.0f);
        c.setCenterY(150.0f);
        c.setRadius(100.0f);
        c.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        c.setFill(null);

        root.getChildren().add(c);

        int N = 16;
        Circle pt = null;
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            pt = new Circle(150.0f + 100 * Math.cos(Math.PI*2*(i/N)),
                    150.0f + 100 * Math.sin(Math.PI*2*(i/N)), 3.0f);
            pt.setFill(Color.BLACK);
            root.getChildren().add(pt); 
        }

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

I'd assume that the position of the point (circle) should change as i increases. Maybe this is wrong?

Comment: can you share the whole code and not just a snippet?

Comment: @Fredlo2010 sorry, updated it!

Comment: they way you are calculating the coordinates is wrong. It's giving you the same coordinates always. You are printing 16 circles just on top of each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the way you calculate the angle. You want to multiply the "progress" around the circle as a value between `0` and `1` by the value that would be used for `i=16` (`2 * PI`).

This approach is correct but you're doing a ***integer division***:

```
(i / N)
```

The result of this division is truncated and since for all `i`: `0 <= i < N` the expression always evaluates to `0`.

If you convert one of the values to a floating point type or simply remove the brackets, your approach works:

```
int N = 16;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    Circle pt = new Circle(150.0f + 100 * Math.cos(Math.PI * 2 * i / N),
            150.0f + 100 * Math.sin(Math.PI * 2 * i / N), 3.0f);
    pt.setFill(Color.BLACK);
    root.getChildren().add(pt);
}
```

Removing the brackets works, since `Math.PI * 2 * i / N` is equivalent to `((Math.PI * 2) * i) / N` and the multiplication of a `double` like `Math.PI` and a `int` yields `double`.

Answer (score 0):

OK this should work. I changed a lot of stuff because you seem line a new programmer so I thought I would give you a few words of wisdom.

1. The more explicit you are in the program the better. So do not write stuff together all the time. Separate them into logic units and you will safe yourself a lot of headaches.
2. Software variables are not the same thing as math variables. Give them long expressive names no short ones. Your code would read like poetry (not sure who I heard this from but I like a lot)
3. Let and IDE guide you. Start typing and press Ctrl+Space a few times and see what comes up.
4. If your logic get's too long and it can be separated into a new function; do it so.

Here is the final code.

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 300, Color.LIGHTGREY);
        Circle circle = new Circle(150.0f, 150.0f, 100.0f, Color.TRANSPARENT);
        circle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

        List<Node> dots = getCircledDots(16, circle, 3.0f);

        root.getChildren().add(circle);
        root.getChildren().addAll(dots);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * Function to create list of dots around a circle.
     */
    private List<Node> getCircledDots(int numberOfDots, Circle circle, double dotRadius) {

        List<Node> dots = new ArrayList<>();
        double angleFactor = 2 * Math.PI / numberOfDots;
        double originX = circle.getCenterX();
        double originY = circle.getCenterY();
        double radius = circle.getRadius();
        double angle;
        Circle dot = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDots; i++) {

            angle = i * angleFactor;
            double x = originX + radius * Math.cos(angle);
            double y = originY + radius * Math.sin(angle);

            dot = new Circle(x, y, dotRadius);
            dot.setFill(Color.BLACK);
            dots.add(dot);
        }
        return dots;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it was using a simple for loop and find `x` and `y` co-ordinates in cartesian:
This was centered at `[50, 50, 50]` and numpoint is the number of points you want in the circle: if you translate along location 3 (along `z` axis) , you can possibly get a cylinder

```
    double radius = 5.0;
    double theta = Math.toRadians(360/numpoint);
    double[]loc=new double[3];
    for (int i = 1; i <= numpoint; i++) {

        loc[0] = (double)(50+(radius * Math.cos(theta*i)));
        loc[1] = (double)(50+(radius * Math.sin(theta*i)));
        loc[2] = 50+0;

    }
```